# Laravel Sanctum Angular Authentication 419 error code

Tags: php, angular, laravel-sanctum

I'm trying to setup an authentication system using Laravel Sanctum and Fortify for the back-end and Angular for the front-end.

The front-end is running on localhost:4200
the back-end is running on: localhost:8000

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2zKoS8GsKK8&t=612s) tutorial for the common mistakes and set the .env file accordingly
so it looks like this:

```
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:4200
FRONTEND_URL=http://localhost:4200
```

and so is my cors.php configuration:

```php
<?php

return [

  

    'paths' => ['*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => [env('FRONTEND_URL', 'http://localhost:4200')],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

];
```

For logging in my users I'm using this angular service function:

```js
options = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      Accept: 'application/json',
    }),
    withCredentials: true,
  }

login(email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
      .get(this.baseUrl + '/sanctum/csrf-cookie', this.options)
      .pipe(
        switchMap(() =>
          this.http.post(
            this.baseUrl + '/login',
            { email, password },
            this.options
          )
        )
      );
  }
```

the problem is that when I try to login I get back a 419 erro code saying that the CSRF token mismatches.

taking a look at the cookies inside the browser's console the list is empty so no cookies are passed even if the request to /csrf-cookie is successfull

What am I doing wrong her? is it the angular service or my back-end config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem after asking on every possible source, let's talk about it:

Looks like that specifically on MacOS, if you try to send a request from localhost:4200 Origin and Refero headers will not match the `Host` header for some reason

i solved this changing every `localhost` occurrence in my Laravel .env and config files and then going to 127.0.0.1:4200 inside the browser instead of localhost:4200

it's a bit weird to explain but it makes requests come to the same source even if the localhost keyword should mean 127.0.0.1 IP by default

hope this will help someone